# Error -60005 when install Cocos2d-iPhone v3 RC4

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

When I try to install `Cocos2d-iphone 3.0.0 RC4`, I got an error: (run without **`sudo`**)

```
Error -60005 occurred while executing script with privileges.
```

So, I try to show its package content and use terminal to do: `cd ...Cocos2D Installer 3.0.0.app/Contents/MacOS`

I try this command: (with **`sudo`**)

```
sudo ./Cocos2D\ Installer\ 3.0.0
```

It works but I got log with some errors:

```
[1m>>> Installing Cocos2D-v3.0.0 files (B[m
[1m>>> Installing Cocos2D-v3.0.0 templates (B[m

[4m[1mCocos2D Template Installer (Cocos2D-v3.0.0)(B[m


Error: [31m✖︎(B[m Script cannot be executed as root.
       In order for it to work properly, please execute the script again without 'sudo'.

If you want to know more about how to use this script execute '/Users/viethung/Downloads/Cocos2D-v3.0.0/install.sh --help'.

[1m>>> Building/Installing Cocos2D-v3.0.0 documentation, this may take a minute.... (B[m
appledoc version: 2.2 (build 963)

Generation step 4/5 failed: GBDocSetInstallGenerator failed generating output, aborting!
Documentation set was installed, but couldn't reload documentation within Xcode.
Xcode got an error: No documentation set present at specified path.
[1m>>> Cocos2D-v3.0.0 installation complete! (B[m
```

Are there any way is better than this way?

Comment: have you trued re-downloading the package? Sounds like it is corrupt.

Comment: The way i read the post , seems you are sudo'ing the installer , and it is whining that you cant run it as root i.e. dont sudo, just run it. Although it would not be the firs time an error message was bogus, i'd give that a try.

Comment: @LearnCocos2D: Thanks but I dont think so. Because it worked OK on other mac

Comment: @YvesLeBorg: If I run without "**`sudo`**", I got error -60005

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have same problem.

I think you installed old cocos2d-iphone and it caused this problem.

You should remove old cocos2d-iphone first. I removed:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/cocos2d v3.x
```

And install again. It works for me.

Hope it works for you :)

Comment: Yes, you are right. I installed cocos3d rc3. Thanks! :D